# heroku push rejected. error fetching custom buildpack

Tags: angularjs, heroku, push, buildpack

I am trying to push an angularJS web app to heroku for the very first time and unable to do so because of this error. I have done decent amount of research on this error on/off SO, tried a few things but to no avail. I am not sure about what 'buildpack' it is referring to. App runs fine on localhost:8000. Appreciate your help.

> $ git push heroku master
>   Counting objects: 2122, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (1890/1890), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (2122/2122), 3.25 MiB | 138.00 KiB/s, done.
>   Total 2122 (delta 236), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   remote: Compressing source files... done.
>   remote: Building source:
>   remote:
>   remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... failed
>   remote:
>   remote:  !     Push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack
>   remote:
>   remote: Verifying deploy...
>   remote:
>   remote: ! Push rejected to evening-wildwood-9283.
>   remote:
>   To https://git.heroku.com/evening-wildwood-9283.git
>   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/evening-wildwood-9283.git'

Comment: Does the application run on Node.js or Rails?  During compilation, it Heroku will search for the server side application structure as listed in this link.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: hi the app has neither node.js or rails sever setup, i was able to run it using python simplehttpserver and it works just fine.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if a backend is required, I don't think heroku is meant to be a straight up file server but I could be wrong

Comment: Is it just static site?  Setting it ups with a python simplehttpserver is different than backing your site with a supported buildpack. You might want to consider a different hosting service.  Heroku is best for Node.js or Ruby server side type applications.  You don't need a Maserati when a Pinto would do just fine!  See the following links to get a site them set up these ways if you want.  Git Pages is also a great way to hose static sites.   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku https://pages.github.com/

Comment: thanks snew, snowman4425, i will check it out.